# Adding numberless chapters to the table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

How do I include a chapter reference within the table of contents *without* giving it a chapter number? I am using the report document class.

Normally, I would create a chapter as follows:

```
\chapter{Some Chapter}
```

but this results in the chapter being given a number. Currently I am using

```
\chapter*{Some Chapter}
```

which gets rid of the number, but then it is absent from the table of contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Some chapter}
```

just after your `\chapter*{Some chapter}`. For an automated approach, define your own `\chapter` command (say) `\mychapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapter}{s o m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
    {\global\edef\chapToCname{#3}}
    {\global\edef\chapToCname{#2}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \mychapter*
     \chapter*[\chapToCname]{#3}%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\chapToCname}
    }{% \mychapter
     \chapter [\chapToCname]{#3}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{A chapter}
\mychapter*{Some chapter}
\end{document}
```

The macro interface is provided by [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

Answer (score 11):

You can insert it using `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter*{Another chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for the sake of completeness:

If you would use one of the `KOMA-script` classes `scrbook` or `scrreprt`, you could use the command `\addchap`, which provides exactly what you want.