# Displaying table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding numberless chapters to the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45672/adding-numberless-chapters-to-the-table-of-contents)

I'm currently writing my report and I wasn't able to create my table of content properly. The fact is that I only use things like chapter*{...} because the text "Chapter X" bothers me, it takes a lot of place and currently isn't usefull in my report.
So how can I write my tables of contents with my chapters even if they have a * ?

Comment: Use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Your chapter name}`.

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar it workd. Sorry for the possible duplicate my research on google didn't find that thread. I don't know the exact terms in english.

Comment: @Depado please post an answer if you have solved your issue.

Comment: @HarishKumar Seemingly your comment resolved the problem. If so could you post it as an answer.

Comment: @HarishKumar Waiting for your answer to validate.