# How to remove the chapter prefix only from a Preface chapter in scrbook?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding numberless chapters to the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45672/adding-numberless-chapters-to-the-table-of-contents)

how can I remove "1" from the Preface chapter:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\begin{document}
        \tableofcontents
        \chapter{Preface}
        \setcounter{chapter}{0}
        \part{One}
        \chapter{First}
        \part{Two}
        \chapter{Second}
\end{document}
```

I have found the "chapterprefix" parameter inthe KOMA-Script documentation, but this option seems to be a global one. I just need to have the Preface chapter without the "1" prefix.

Comment: `\addchap{Preface}`

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45672/adding-numberless-chapters-to-the-table-of-contents), particularly Speravir's answer that's better than the accepted one. Let us know if the linked question helps, so we can close this as duplicate.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, egreg: thanks, \addchap together with \addsec works!