# Chapter in ToC without page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page

I'm working in sharelatex and a requirement for my thesis is a summary in the ToC which is an unnumbered chapter and without page number. Now, I fixed the numberless chapter, but there is no documentation of latex of excluding the page number for a single chapter in the ToC. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are using a KOMA class `\addchap{Foo}` otherwise you need `\newcommand*{\fakeaddchap}[1]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\chaptermark{#1}}` (that could be made nicer: should be aware of the optional argument etc., etc.) See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45672/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11668/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199071/35864

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434166/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the page number in the ToC you can add the ToC entry manually with `\addtocontents`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand\fakechapter[2][]{%
  \ifx&#1&%
    \fakechapter[#2]{#2}%
  \else
    \chapter*{#2}%
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{#1}{}}%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\fakechapter{Abc}
\chapter{Def}
\fakechapter[Something]{Ghi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I discovered that`\contentsline` used as above will result in trouble when used with hyperref (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/589153/extra-curly-bracket-error-when-using-contentsline-and-hyperref/590332#590332).  `\contentsline` takes four arguments and hyperref will abort the build if they're not all there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `memoir` class (which caters for the `book`, `report`, and `article` classes) you can do this:

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter*{Summary} % No ToC entry
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} % no chapter page numbers
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary} % put Summary chapter title in ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}} % chapter page numbers printed - edited brackets    
Summary of the thesis.
\chapter{One}
Your thesis ...
\end{document}
```