# How to add indent in non-numbered section of the table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I'm using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to show sections without any number. It works as expected, but I'd like to have some indentation to align the begin of the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text1.tex}
     \section{text 1}
    \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text2.tex}
    \section{text 2}
    \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text3.tex}
    \section{text 3}
    \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text4.tex}
    \section{text 4}
\blindtext
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\inputa}[1]{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 
    \input{#1}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
}

\begin{document}    
\input{text1.tex}
\inputa{text2.tex}
\input{text3.tex}
\input{text4.tex}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Giving the following result:
[image: unaligned entries]

I'd like all the words "text" to be aligned.

[EDIT after Phelype Oleinik answere]

Regarding the suggested non-starred approach: I will not manually change my numerous sections consisting of a lot of different .tex files. I've once tried to make it automated writing my `\inputa` command with something like:

```
\newcounter{starlab}%counter for a label to use with \nameref
\newcommand{\inputa}[1]{%
    \let\origsection\section
    \renewcommand{\section}{% force starred section
        \@ifstar{\origsection*}{\origsection*}}
    \input{#1}
    \refstepcounter{starlab}\label{sec:\thestarlab}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\nameref{sec:\thestarlab}}
    \let\orgisection\section
    }
```

But…

1. I cannot compile it anymore, I don't know why (`Argument of \@ssect has an extra }` error).
2. yersterday it worked on my document with the desired appearance, but I still had a problem with `hypperef` since the label points at the end of the text, and those texts are sometimes quite long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{section}
    {}
    {\etocifnumbered
      {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
      {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\numberline{}\etocname}{\etocpage}}%
    }
    {}
    {}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Alpaca}
\blindtext
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Capybara}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\blindtext
\section{Ant}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is with MWE from OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{section}
    {}
    {\etocifnumbered
      {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
      {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\numberline{}\etocname}{\etocpage}}%
    }
    {}
    {}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text1.tex}
     \section{text 1}
    \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text2.tex}
    \section{text 2}
    \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text3.tex}
    \section{text 3}
    \blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text4.tex}
    \section{text 4}
\blindtext
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\inputa}[1]{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 
    \input{#1}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
}

\begin{document}    
\input{text1.tex}
\inputa{text2.tex}
\input{text3.tex}
\input{text4.tex}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this solution supposes the table of contents contains no subsection etc... but it can easily be extended to cope with it. (see `18. Another compatibility mode` in [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) documentation.

Comment: Nice package, I'm using it and I will read the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I changed your approach a bit... Instead of changing `secnumdepth` in the middle of the document, you can use the starred version `\section*` to add a numberless section.

(If you insist on changing `secnumdepth`, see the second part of the answer).

Then you can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{text 2}` to add this section's entry to the ToC.

Better yet! You can use

```
\section*{text 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}text 2}
```

and the indentation will be preserved in the ToC, as you want:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{text 1}
\blindtext

\section*{text 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}text 2}
\blindtext

\section{text 3}
\blindtext
\section{text 4}
\blindtext

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

To make things less manual, you can define a command, say, `\nonumbersection` to do the whole thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter
\def\nonumbersection{\@dblarg\@nnsection}
\def\@nnsection[#1]#2{%
  \section*{#2}%
  \sectionmark{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{text 1}
\blindtext

\nonumbersection{text 2}
\blindtext

\section{text 3}
\blindtext
\section{text 4}
\blindtext

\nonumbersection[t5]{text 5}
\blindtext

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

---

As per your edit, if you insist on keeping the `secnumdepth` approach:

Your definition of `\inputa` is *almost* correct, except:

- The `\refstepcounter`, `\label`, and `\addcontentsline` commands should me *inside* the new definition of `\section`, because this `\section` command will be inside the `\input`, and if you place the `\label` after the `\input` it's too late, and the reference will be wrong (as you concluded yourself);
- The de-redefinition of `\section` is incorrect. You had `\let\orgisection\section`, which will make a copy of `\section` into `\orgisection`, but you want the opposite, so it's `\let\section\orgisection`;
- It's `\origsection` :P

After the corrections, your code works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text1.tex}
\section{text 1}
\blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text2.tex}
\section{text 2}
\blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text3.tex}
\section{text 3}
\blindtext
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{text4.tex}
\section{text 4}
\blindtext
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{starlab}%counter for a label to use with \nameref
\newcommand{\inputa}[1]{%
    \let\origsection\section
    \def\section{%
      \refstepcounter{starlab}%
      \label{sec:\thestarlab}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\nameref{sec:\thestarlab}}
      \@ifstar{\origsection*}{\origsection*}}
    \input{#1}
    \let\section\origsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\input{text1.tex}
\inputa{text2.tex}
\input{text3.tex}
\input{text4.tex}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: In a document with running heads one might also want `\sectionmark`. And maybe `\nonumbersection` could support the optional short argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but I would prefer not to change my numerous sections which are on different texfiles. I've edited my answer to be more precise.

Comment: @moewe I updated my answer to incorporate your suggestions. Thanks :)

Comment: @omisson I updated my answer with a version that works (I hope) with the structure of your document.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a conflict somewhere with my custom documentclass and y get double numbered entries with this code. But it was smart and very interesting to read. Finally, I'm using the `etoc` package.

Comment: @omisson Unfortunately this is the price we sometimes have to pay for using minimal examples :/ Glad to know jfbu's answer worked for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Using [`unnumberedtotoc`](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/):

[image: omissonUnnumbered]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[indentunnumbered]{unnumberedtotoc}%<----------
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Alpaca}
\blindtext
\addsec[Wombat]{Capybara}
\blindtext
\section{Ant}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```