# Extra curly bracket error when using \contentsline and hyperref

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, chapters, page-numbering, books

I want to have some commentary text below the chapter name when in the table of contents. Following [Chapter in ToC without page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434146/chapter-in-toc-without-page-number) I adapted this to create a `\fakesection` command to suppress the page number.  It looks great (see rendering below) but it will not coexist with the `hyperref` package.  The second pass of `pdflatex` fails like this:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./test.out) (./test.out) (./test.toc
! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \contentsline
                  {chapter}{\numberline {2}EFGH}{5}{chapter.2}%
?
```

If I have just one chapter, this is the result instead:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./test.out) (./test.out) (./test.toc)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \contentsline.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.23 \tableofcontents
                     
?
```

Here's an MWE and the rendering of the TOC:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Uncommenting this will result in ! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.
%\usepackage[pdfusetitle,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand\fakesection[2][]{%
  \ifx&#1&%
    \fakesection[#2]{#2}%
  \else
    \section*{#2}%
    \sectionmark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{#1}{}}%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}%
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{200}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{ABCD}
\fakesection{The First Four Letters}
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{EFGH}
\fakesection{The Next Four Letters}
\lipsum[6-10]
\chapter{IJKL}
\fakesection{Halfway Through}
\lipsum[11-15]
\chapter{MNOP}
\fakesection{The Middle of the Alphabet}
\lipsum[16-20]
\chapter{QRST}
\fakesection{Over the Hill of Letters}
\lipsum[21-25]
\chapter{UVWX}
\fakesection{Almost Done}
\lipsum[26-30]
\chapter{YZ}
\fakesection{The Two Stragglers}
\lipsum[31-35]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: contentsline should have four arguments, and remove the `\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\@gobble}` (or put something in argument three that the \@gobble can handle.)

Comment: This did the trick.  Would you please do this again as an answer so you can get proper credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\contentsline` should have *four* arguments, as hyperref requires this (it stores the destination name in the fourth argument). In a current LaTeX `\contentsline` has always four arguments, so it doesn't harm to use four arguments even if hyperref is not involved.

Also remove the `\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\@gobble}` or put something in the third argument of `\contentsline` that the `\@gobble` can actually handle.