# Issues with vertical spacing and \addcontentsline

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing

The code `\vskip\baselineskip\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}` produces a vertical space equal to `\baselineskip`, as it should.
However, when I add `\addcontentsline` in the middle, I get a bigger space:

```
\vskip\baselineskip%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}%
\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
    A
    
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    b
    
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
    A
    
    \vskip\baselineskip%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}%
    \addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    b
    
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
    A
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    b
    
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\addtocontents in TeXLive 2022 vs 2021 and previous releases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667762/addtocontents-in-texlive-2022-vs-2021-and-previous-releases)

Comment: hm but maybe not, let me investigate a bit more

Comment: @Marijn I've tried using the `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{SomethingA}{SomethingB}{}}%`, but nothing changed

Comment: I retracted my close vote, it is a different issue. I think what is happening is that in the leftmost minipage the `\addvspace` is actually ignored (commenting it out doesn't change the output, effectively turning it into the rightmost minipage) but in the middle one `\addcontentsline` introduces all kinds of grouping and phantomsections etc. that allows `\addvspace` to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

`\addvspace` probes `\lastskip`.  But the `\addcontentsline` adds a special which causes TeX to report it as zero.

[image: 3 small minipages]

from

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
    A
    
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \the\lastskip
    b
    
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
    A
    
    \vskip\baselineskip%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}%
    \the\lastskip
    b
    
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
    A
    
    \the\lastskip
    b
    
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

I do not know off-hand apart from hacking `\addcontentsline` how to modify this state of affairs.